# Duplicate row but update a field in json

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm trying to duplicate all rows in my table that contain a `signalVersion: prod` but in the duplicated row I'd like to set `signalVersion` to `0`. There are two keys in my table, `signal_key` and `signal_value` and both are json objects. `signalVersion` is a property of the object in column `signal_key`. Below is an example of `signal_key`:

```
{
  "signalType": "OCR_ITEM", 
  "signalVersion": "prod"
}
```

This is the code I've written so far but it's failing. Does anyone know why my syntax is incorrect?

```
insert into signals (signal_key, signal_value)
select signal_key -> '{"signalVersion": "0"}', signal_value
from signals
where signal_key @> '{"signalVersion": "prod"}';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`||` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to merge `{"signalVersion": "0"}` into the `signal_key`, not `->`:

```
insert into signals (signal_key, signal_value)
select signal_key || '{"signalVersion": "0"}', signal_value
from signals
where signal_key @> '{"signalVersion": "prod"}';
```

Alternatively, you could use `json_set`:

```
insert into signals (signal_key, signal_value)
select json_set(signal_key, array['signalVersion'], 0), signal_value
from signals
where signal_key @> '{"signalVersion": "prod"}';
```